# macOS app cannot be "developer ID" distributed (option doesn't show)

Tags: xcode, macos, software-distribution

I have a little terminal app that I want to distribute.

I have a valid "developer ID" certificate generated by the Team admin installed in my keychain (I can see it's public and private key )

In Xcode, in the "signing & Capabilities", I added the "Hardened Runtime" capabilities.
When selecting the "signing Certificate" while "automatically manage signing" is on, I can't select "developer ID application" certificate.

[image]

When I turn off  "automatically manage signing"
"developer ID appliciation" can be selected, there are no warning and error.

[image]

But when I archive the application, I click on "Distribute content"
and The "Developer ID" distribution method doesn't appear.

[image]

what am I missing ?
I already tried deleting the "db" file in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/ as other threads suggested.

thank you.

Comment: Do you have both the "Developer ID Application" and "Developer ID Installer" certificates and keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons I am talking about in my question are not available anymore in the latest version of Xcode. You got to export your app using the "buit product" options, and then notarize your app using apple's documentation.